# ActiveAdmin export columns for all formats?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

What's the syntax to export the same columns in a single configuration to CSV and JSON for instance, e.g. the CSV configuration:

```
  csv do
    column :id
    column "Person" do |relation|
      relation.person.name
    end
    column :created_at
    column :updated_at
  end
```

Goal: get rid of an overhead defining the same block again for JSON.

Answer (score 0):

I would make a collection_action that returns the desired columns in different format.